# regex find & replace before or after ;_

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to add a list.
For example if i have this:

```
Fits 10" - 24" TVs ;_ Holds up to 80lbs ;_ Mounts to a single wood stud, concrete or cinder block ;_ Low-profile design holds screen less than 1" from the wall ;_
```

Question 1: How to add `<li>` before and `</li>` after ;_ with regex
As such:

```
<ul>;_  <li>Fits 10" - 24" TVs</li>;_   <li>Holds up to 80lbs</li>;_    <li>Mounts to a single wood stud, concrete or cinder block</li>;_   <li>Low-profile design holds screen less than 1" from the wall</li>;_   </ul>'
```

And question 2: how to at `<ul>` and `</ul>` at the end of list if possible or (if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use followed:

```
$s =  ".. ;_ ..";
$list = explode(';_', $s);
$html = "<ul><li>".implode('</li><li>', $list)."</li></ul>";
```

Or even:

```
echo "<ul><li>".implode('</li><li>', explode(';_', ".. ;_ .."))."</li></ul>";
```

Looks like regular ;)

**Add:**

In pseudocode, because I don't know what database API you are using.

```
  if (!($q = $db->query("SELECT id, html FROM wp_table_name"))) {
    throw new Exception("No rows returned");
  }
  $rows = array();
  while ($row = $q->fetch_object()) {
    $db->query("UPDATE wp_table_name SET html = ? WHERE id = ?", array(
      "<ul><li>".implode('</li><li>', explode(';_', $row->html))."</li></ul>",
      $row->id
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, i am trying to modify table called wp_qtvd_posts. Can i explode with sql?

Comment: I used: <ul /><?php echo $post->post_content; ?> to input <ul> tags around text but i still cant figure out how to explode text to add <li> before and after ;_

Comment: You cannot add it before and after, only instead, if you want to show this lists in the browsers

Comment: Ok but when i use echo "<ul><li>".implode('</li><li>', explode(';_', ".. ;_ .."))."</li></ul>"; it just prints out bullet with .. after the paragraph.

Comment: ".. ;_ .." means your `;_` separated text :) "Fits 10.." and so other

Comment: Ok thanks! Sorry for a lot of questions but what does $s mean in first example?

Comment: just a variable with same content (Your "Fits 10..") :)

Comment: Thanks, one more question. Is it possible to combine <ul /><?php echo $post->post_content; ?> 
with echo "<ul><li>".implode('</li><li>', explode(';_', ".. ;_ .."))."</li></ul>"? Many thanks

Comment: what in your $post->post_content? if here `;_` separated string, then write: `<?php echo "<ul><li>".implode('</li><li>', explode(';_', $post->post_content))."</li></ul>" ?>` You should learn some theory before starting some coding...

Comment: I cant thank you enough!! Finally i got it to work! Now thats over with i agree i need to start learning.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex. Use `explode`:

```
$string = 'Fits 10" - 24" TVs ;_ Holds up to 80lbs ;_ Mounts to a single wood stud, concrete or cinder block ;_ Low-profile design holds screen less than 1" from the wall ;_';
$items = expode(';_', $string);
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (!empty(trim($item)) { // This may throw an error if your PHP version is old
        echo '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but when i applied this to php file it breaks my theme